# I need a transfer function for salt water balance control mechanism in human kidney to run on a matlab.

Tags: mathematical-modeling

I want to model the control system mechanism of salt water balance in human kidney with the transfer function technique.
But I am having problem finding the transfer function from the mathematical transport equations.

Comment: Hint. Transfer function is an alternative way to write the ordinary differential equations (ODE) underlying a certain dynamical system. Have you searched on Google "Salt water balance human kidney dynamical model ODE"?

Comment: Thank you. I will try that..